(CS50p Problem Set 6 Scourgify) scourgify.py does not produce CSV with specified format
required format: Run your program with python scourgify.py before.csv after.csv. Assuming before.csv exists, your program should create a new file, after.csv, whose columns should be, in order, first, last, and house.
When I run my code, it looks like my after.csv has the correct format but check50 disagrees. Could someone help me find where I went wrong?
my code:
import csv
import sys

def main():

## check number of args
    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
        sys.exit("Too few command-line arguments")
    elif len(sys.argv) < 3:
        sys.exit("Too many command-line arguments")

    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
## csv check
        if str.endswith(sys.argv[1], ".csv") and str.endswith(sys.argv[2], ".csv"):
## check if we have file
            try:
                test = open(sys.argv[1])

            except FileNotFoundError:
                sys.exit(f"Could not read {sys.argv[1]}")

## actual manipulation
            else:
                with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as input, open(sys.argv[2], "w") as output:
                    reader = csv.DictReader(input)
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames = ["first", "last", "house"])
                    writer.writeheader()

                    for row in reader:
                        first, last = str.split(row["name"], ",")
                        first = first.strip()
                        last = last.strip()
                        writer.writerow(
                            {
                                "first": first,
                                "last": last,
                                "house": row["house"]
                            }
                        )
        else:
            sys.exit("Not a .csv file")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I tried using check50, I expected all smiles but ended up with it pointing out a formatting error that I can't identify.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Look carefully and critically at the output this program produces. Is it in the requested format, "columns....in order, first, last, and house"? Notice the supplied input file is not in that order. (E.G. Harry,Potter,Hogwarts

Could you explain this to me in more detail? My after.csv has a header row of "first,last,house" which to my understanding is what they are asking me for.

explanation edited into the answer
